# How to call core functions in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I  developed a plugin for CRUD in wordpress it is working fine but as per wordpress norms we can not call core functions directly. 
I called function in following manner. what is right way for that.
Include(/../../wp-config.php);

Comment: Hi If you develop plugins for CRUD then you don't need to include config file same as you mention. Batter way is used WP_List_Table Class and create it.

Comment: I used this because I created multiple pages for example a page for all user called alluser.php at that time I required this file otherwise it will show error and data will not show.

Comment: Can you share your file code for review Or share which function you want to call from core file? Because if you want to access database then you can user global $wpdb etc.

Comment: I have used  global $wpdb  but it is not working.

Comment: can you explain more about your alluser.php file. If you develop wordpress plugins then its work but for that need to follow wordpress stander.

Comment: Here is my code on Github https://github.com/Viv31/Wordpress_CRUD_Plugin

Answer (score 0):

for that you will have to include "wp-load.php" from root directory

Comment: Will this work on all the pages associated to plugin .

Comment: If you add hook-like wp_init(),wp_head(),wp_footer() then it will work on all pages

Comment: Here is my code on Github https://github.com/Viv31/Wordpress_CRUD_Plugin please review this.